# Is it possible to run ATL service as user application

Tags: c++, service

I have to develop ATL app that is meant to run as service most the time, however we need to deploy it as user application in few environments

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the answer is no, but I could easily be wrong - in either case however this probably isn't the approach I would take.  Personally in your situation I would either:

- Develop 2 apps, a service and a user application, or
- Develop a console application and use the Windows Server 2003 resource kit to run it as a service.

See [here](http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=197) for instructions on how to run any Application as a Windows service (I'm sure there are better guides out there, but I'm struggling to find them at the moment)

Comment: What if I implement my own WinMain and run alternate run() loop for specific command line switch like "/app" or so?

Comment: @grzegorz_p, sounds like you already have the answer to your own question.